# MS Access: Seeking to Change the BG Color of a Combo Box's DROPDOWN Only. Possible?

Tags: ms-access, combobox, dropdownbox

Everyone,

I've created a datasheet in a MS Access application that will have extensive entries when done. Each line is a single row of controls, some of which are text boxes, others of which are combo boxes.

The problem is that when there are many rows displayed on the screen, and the user clicks on a combo box, the contents of that combo box pretty much disappear against the rows behind it, because they all have the same font color/size and the same BG color, and almost no borders at all. .

I would like to be able to change the BG color of the combo boxes' ***DROPDOWN only***, not the BG of the combo box itself. This would allow the dropdown to be easily seen against the rows behind it, and much easier for this application's users to quickly zero in on where they need to focus their attention.

This is important, because at least half of the users of this application will be over 60, and at least a dozen I know of much older than that. They really need things that are easier to see, not harder.

Is this even possible in Access?

TIA for any help.

David in Mississippi

Comment: There is no intrinsic property for this. If Windows API code could do it, it would not be simple. Don't underestimate us over-60ers.

Comment: Perhaps should use a continuous form with controls arranged to look like datasheet. Then form background color can contrast with combobox dropdown. However, users won't be able to resize column widths.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as far as I know.

Having said that, if readability is your main concern, you can open the data sheet in design view and change the `alternate row colour` property to have the alternate rows have different colours.

A dropdown box will not have alternating colour so this should stand out clearly.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion, krish KM, but alternating row colors only affects BG color of the rows, and all the fields on my data form have zero (exterior) margins, i.e., they are butted up against each other to make best use of space, so the row BG colors won't show through. Thanks anyway. I was hopeful, but alas.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the background color of the combobox to the color you want to see for the dropdown list
2. change the back style of the combobox to 'transparent.' This will automatically change the back color to 'no color' but the previous color will still be used for the drop down list.
3. since the combobox is transparent, you'll have to decide what to do next.  If you're ok with whatever is behind it showing, then you're done. Otherwise a simple trick is to position a solid-color rectangle the same size as your combobox directly behind it, using the color you actually want.